# How to get doctrine from abstract class in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

In my code I need to download from database some data and put it to the form, but I don't know how to get doctrone outside Controller class.

I tried create new service, but it didn't work (I think I can't use in this case __controller(), am I right?). I tried also transfer instance of the controller to the parameters of buildForm() method but I got message: `FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of MyBundle\Form\Type\TemplateType::buildForm() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::buildForm()` ).

This is my code:

```
class TemplateType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            // ...
            ->add('description', 'textarea');
    }
    public function getName() {
        return 'template';
    }
}
```

How can I use inside buildForm() doctrine?

Comment: I think you should use the same principle used in the CRUD code with the scaffolding tool, particularly the part that is concerning 'Edit Object'.

Comment: I found solution: I used Entity Field Type to download data from database.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send data from doctrine to your form, you need to do this into your controller:

```
public function doSomethingWithOneObjectAction( $id )
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository( 'AcmeBundle:ObjectEntity' )->find( $id );

    if ( ! $entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException( 'Unable to find Object entity.' );
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(
        new TemplateType(),
        $entity
    );

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

If you want to access a service from container inside your form type, you need first to register it as an service and inject into it the services you need. Something like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service)

Comment: I can't do that becouse I need to download some extra data from database in buildForm() to render my form.

Comment: Then you should register your form type as a service and inject doctrine service into it, as suggested in the last phrase